# Getting the "wrong" type generated with SQLAlchemy 0.7.8 and Oracle XE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlalchemy

Can anyone please tell me why the DateTime type below creates a "DATE" object and not a DateTime (or more appropriately, a TIMESTAMP type) as I have to force the type as in the row below :

```
#!/bin/python

import sqlalchemy

from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Index, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.dialects import oracle

Base = declarative_base()

import logging

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine').setLevel(logging.INFO)

class TypeTest(Base):
    __tablename__ = "TYPETESTZ"
    thisisinteger = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    thisisnotadatetime = Column(DateTime)
    thisisdatetime = Column(oracle.TIMESTAMP)    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('oracle://richard:password@xe')
    metadata = Base.metadata
    metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Log output:

```
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT USER FROM DUAL
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE table_name = :name AND owner = :schema_name
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{'name': u'TYPETESTZ', 'schema_name': u'RICHARD'}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:
CREATE TABLE "TYPETESTZ" (
    thisisinteger INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    thisisnotadatetime DATE, 
    thisisdatetime TIMESTAMP, 
    PRIMARY KEY (thisisinteger)
)


INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:{}
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine:COMMIT
```

Answer (score 2):

Oracle does not have a `DateTime` data type.  In Oracle, a `Date` contains both a day (i.e. August 21, 2012) and a time (i.e. 1:30 PM) with granularity of 1 second.  A `Timestamp`, without additional qualifiers, merely allows you to increase the granularity to nanoseconds (10^-9 seconds).  It seems reasonable for SQLAlchemy to translate a `DateTime` to an Oracle `Date` unless there is some requirement that the `DateTime` supports fractional seconds (in which case you would need a `Timestamp`) or time zones (in which case you would need a `Timestamp with [local] time zone`).

Comment: I agree with what you say but I'm not sure about the conclusion... if I wanted to store something that had a granularity of 0.01 (whatever units), I would hope that the default would be to put it in a datatype that could store at least 0.01, and not round it up to 100 .. Interestingly enough, when I created the tables manually, then SQLAlchemy had no issue with using timestamps in lieu of DateTime objects, but when I decided to drop/ recreate via SQLAlchemy that's when I hit this issue. How can I force SQLA to map a DateTime -> Timestamp for all occurences ?

Answer (score 0):

To create a `TIMESTAMP` object you may want to use `Time` like

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Time, Index, MetaData
```

Although, `DateTime` in `sqlalchemy` would get a TIMESTAMP with TIMEZONE only if `TIMEZONE` is set to `TRUE`. Default is `FALSE`.

> class sqlalchemy.types.DateTime(timezone=**False**)
>
> **init**(timezone=False) Construct a new DateTime.
>
> Parameters:   timezone – boolean. If True, and supported by the backend,
>   will produce ‘TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE’. For backends that don’t
>   support timezone aware timestamps, has no effect.

Setting `timezone=True` should work since Oracle does support Timestamp with timezone so you may have to set that.